# How to prevent SSL urls from leaking info?

Tags: security

I was using google SSL search (https:www.google.com) with the expectation that my search would be private. However, my search for 'toasters' produced this query: 
    https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=toasters&aq=f

As you can see, my employer can still log this and see what the search was. How can I make sure that when someone searches on my site using SSL (using custom google search) their search terms isn't made visible.

Comment: Searching for "toasters" at work, eh?

Answer (score 8):

The URL is sent over SSL. Of course a user can see the URL in their own browser, but it isn't visible as it transits the network. Your employer can't log it unless they are the other end of the SSL connection. If your employer creates a CA certificate and installs it in your browser, they could use a proxy to spoof Google host names, but otherwise, the traffic is secure.

Answer (score 2):

HTTPS protects the *entire* HTTP exchange, including the URL, so the only thing someone intercepting network traffic will be able to determine is that there was communication between the browser and your site (or Google in this case).  Even without the innards, that information can be useful.

Unless you have full administrative control over the systems making the queries, you should assume that anything transpiring on them can be intercepted or logged.  Browsers typically store history and cache pages in files on the local disk which can be read by administrators.  You also can't verify that the browser itself hasn't been recompiled with code to log sites that were visited, even in "private" mode.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably your employer provides you with a PC, the software on it, the LAN connection to its own corporate network, the internet proxy and corporate firewall, maybe DNS servers, etc etc.

So you are exposed to traffic sniffing and tracing at many different levels.  Even if you browse to a url over SSL TLS, you have to assume that the contents of your http session can be recorded.  Do you always check that the cert in your browser is from google and not your employer's proxy?  Do you know what software sits between your browser and your network card, etc.

However, if you had **complete control over the client**, then you could be sure that no-one external to your https conversation with google would be able to see the url you are requesting.

Google still knows what you're up to, but that's a private matter between your search engine and your conscience ;)

Comment: As @erickson said, they'd need to replace the certificates (or have full control of the desktop to log keystrokes or other things, which is possible), otherwise, if the just control the proxy they won't see any of the content of the connection (except the host and port of the web server).

Answer (score 0):

to add to what @erickson said, read [this](https://ssl.trustwave.com/support/support-how-ssl-works.php). SSL will protect the data between the connected parties. If you need to hide that link from the boss then disable the browser caching of the sites visited, i.e. disable or delete the history data.